# Making a random SID generator

Tags: powershell

So im definitely close to exactly what im looking for on this. Basically, I have users, and for security purposes, I want their usernames to be randomly generated 7 character SIDs.

example: rgf8uwt or euw2prt or wif5llc

basically it would be 3 letters, then 1 number then 3 more letters

So im trying to create a random generator to do this and what I have so far is:

```
#to create the random number
-join ((48..57) | get-random -Count 1 | % {[char]$_})

#to create the random 3 letter string
-join ((97..122) | Get-Random -Count 3 | % {[char]$_})
```

So now where im stuck is merging the 2 together is a way that it generates a string of characters that is 7 long, with 3 letters, then 1 number, and then 3 letters.

Unless theres a better way to do this that i just dont know about.

Comment: _ for security purposes, I want their usernames to be randomly generated_ -- this is a bad idea. First off, your users will hate you, as no-one remembers strings like euw2prt. Then they will write usernames on a post-it notes and stick those next to screen. Then they will use the same string as their password stuffed with easy to remember suffix like 123 or abc. As result, you think the security has increased because them haxXorz kannot guess account names but actually the security's worse because of the post-its.

Comment: Because you are asking help for the wrong problem. Let's say you fill up your car, and every time you make a huge mess spilling gas all over your pants, hands and whatnot. Then you ask the best way to clean up the mess, since washing clothes still leaves stains on clothes. Instead of getting laundry tips, you should get advice how to fill up without making a mess in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a + it seems to work

```
$Part1 = -join ((97..122) | Get-Random -Count 3 | % {[char]$_})
$Part2 = -join ((48..57) | get-random -Count 1 | % {[char]$_})
$Part3 = -join ((97..122) | Get-Random -Count 3 | % {[char]$_})

$Part1 + $Part2 + $Part3
```